# Difference between throwing new RuntimeException vs casting cause to RuntimeException

Tags: java, exception

Is there a difference between

```
} catch (ExceptionType1 e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

and

```
} catch (ExceptionType1 e) {
    throw (RuntimeException) e.getCause();
}
```

If there is a difference, what should I be checking for in ExceptionType1 to figure out which one is better?

Comment: You'll get a class cast exception if you cast an exception type that is not a runtime exception.

Comment: `RuntimeException` is unchecked, so you might not want to throw it...

Comment: As the difference: The 1st one wraps your exception into a `RuntimeException`, while the 2nd one takes the causing exception from your exception, and casts it as a `RuntimeException`. That latter might cause problems, if it not castable...

Comment: Neither is better. Throwing `RuntimeExceptions` yourself is bad, unless you are one of those unchecked guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of differences:

```
 throw new RuntimeException(e);
```

This wraps whatever exception `e` in a new `RuntimeException`, and throw this `RunTimeException`

---

On the other hand:

```
throw (RuntimeException) e.getCause();
```

This tries to cast the *cause* of whatever exception `e` to a `RuntimeException`. Main differences are:

- You lose the detail of the original exception `e`, as you only attempt to throw its cause (which might be null)
- The cause might not inherit from `RuntimeException` and may not be castable, in which case a `ClassCastException` will occur.